# Why does my terminal only let me type in something and then the code stops?

Tags: perl

I have tried to run this script that I made so poorly and quickly. May someone please point me in the right direction or correct me? When I run the script, it says "What would you like to do with your shopping list?" then, it lets me input something, and then it just stops. Plain stops

```
use Term::ANSIColor;

Menu();

sub Menu {
    print "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
    print "What would you like to do with your shopping list? \n";
    print colored("> Add Item \n", 'bold blue');
    print colored("> Look at list \n", 'bold blue');
    print colored("> Reset \n", 'bold red');
    print colored("> Quit \n", 'bold red');
    print "> ";

    my $a = <STDIN>;
    lc $a;
    chomp $a;

    if ($a == "quit") {
        open (my $fh, '>>', 'list.txt') or die "Couldn't find file!";
        while(<FH>) { 
            print $_; 
        }
        close $fh;
    } else {
        Action();
    }
}

sub Action {
    if ($a == "add" || "add item") {
        open(my $fh, '>>', 'list.txt') or die "Couldn't find file!";
        print "What would you like to add to the list?\n";
        print "> ";
        my $i = <>;
        lc $i;
        chomp $i;
        print "\n";
        print "> ";
        print FH $i;
        print 
        close $fh;
    } elsif ($a == "list" || "look at list") {
        open (my $fh, '>>', 'list.txt') or die "Couldn't find file!";
        while(<FH>) { 
            print $_; 
        } 
        close $fh;
    } elsif ($a == "reset"){
        open (my $fh, '>>', 'list.txt') or die "Couldn't find file!";
        print FH colored("Shopping list", 'bold underline');
        close $fh;
    } else {
        print "Unknown command! Try again.";
        Menu();
    }
}
```

Comment: `use warnings;`

Comment: Tried that, it doesn't work

Comment: `use warnings` is not used to make your code work. It's to show you some of the things you are not doing right.

Comment: It doesn't say anything

Comment: `==` and `||` don't work the way you appear to think they do

Comment: Re "*It doesn't say anything*", That's not true! For starters, it says `Argument "add" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==)`. `$a == "list" || "look at list"` should be `$a eq "list" || $a eq "look at list"`

Comment: I've fixed the indentation in your code to make it easier to follow. You're welcome, of course, but please consider doing that yourself in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Perl has two sets of comparison operators.

The ones that look like maths (`==`, `!=`, `>`, etc.) do a numeric comparison.

The ones that look like words (`eq`, `ne`, `gt`, etc.) do a string comparison.

You have the following:

```
if ($a == "quit") {

...

if ($a == "add" || "add item") {

...

} elsif ($a == "list" || "look at list") {

...

} elsif ($a == "reset"){
```

All of these are doing numeric comparisons. You need to change all of the `==` to `eq`.

Also, this isn't doing what you think it is:

```
if ($a == "add" || "add item") {
```

I think you meant:

```
if ($a eq "add" or $a eq "add item") {
```

In addition, `$a` is a special variable in Perl. Please don't use it in general code. Variable naming is important. Your variable should be called `$action`.

**Update:** It's also worth pointing out that if you had `use warnings` in your code (and you should *always* include `use warnings` in your Perl code) then you would have seen warnings telling you that there was a problem with your code.

```
$ perl -Mwarnings -e'$action = "x"; print "yes" if $action == "quit"'
Argument "quit" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1.
Argument "x" isn't numeric in numeric eq (==) at -e line 1.
```